# Having trouble padding lines to same width in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, markdown

I'm working on Markdown rendering via the terminal in Rust. Currently, I am working on rendering code blocks, and I've had this one issue that has been keeping me up at night.

I am using `pulldown_cmark` crate to parse the markdown, and then I replace the HTML Tags with the proper formatting

When rendering a code block, I highlight the text to represent the fact that it is code, here's what I mean

```rust
html_x
.replace("<code>", "\x1b[7m")
.replace("</code>", "\x1b[27m")
```

One major issue that I am facing is the fact that not all lines have the same length. If y are rendering a code block, the code will have different lengths, meaning that the lines are uneven and one line has more highlight than another. In the following example, whatever is marked with an 'X' represents a part that is not being highlighted.

```rust
let mut a: u8 = 5;
a += 5;XXXXXXXXXXX
println!("{a}");XX
```

You can see how this would make the code block look uneven, and ugly.

I am trying to fix this problem using the [pad](https://docs.rs/pad/latest/pad/) crate. Specifically, I am using the `pad_to_width()` method to add spaces to the lines.

An important thing to note is that I only want to pad lines if they are in a `<pre>` element.

My approach so far has been to split the markdown into lines, and if the line stars with a `<pre>` element, set `in_pre` equal to `true`, and if the line starts with a `</pre>` element, set `in_pre` equal to `false`

Then, while `in_pre` is equal to `true`, loop through the lines and find the longest line. Then, pad the other lines to be the width of the longest line, here is an example:

```rust
line.pad_to_width(longest_line_len);
```

The code to perform this operation looks something like this:

```rust
    // Read the markdown file
    let mut file = File::open(path)?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;

    // Split the contents by lines
    let lines = contents.lines();

    // Loop through the lines and find the shortest and longest line while in_pre is true
    let (mut shortest, mut longest) = (std::usize::MAX, 0);
    let mut in_pre = false;
    let mut formatted_lines = Vec::new();
    for line in lines {
        if line.starts_with("<pre>") {
            in_pre = true;
            continue;
        } else if line.starts_with("</pre>") {
            in_pre = false;
            continue;
        }

        if in_pre {
            let line_len = line.trim().len();
            if line_len < shortest {
                shortest = line_len;
            }
            if line_len > longest {
                longest = line_len;
            }
            formatted_lines.push(line);
        }
    }

    // Pad lines to the length of the longest line
    let formatted_lines: Vec<String> = formatted_lines
        .into_iter()
        .map(|line| {
            if line.trim().len() != longest {
                line.pad_to_width(longest)
            } else {
                line.to_string()
            }
        })
        .collect();
```

However, this doesn't seem to be fixing my issue, and doesn't even seem to be recognizing a `<pre>` element. Even when I set `in_pre` to `true` manually, it still doesn't pad the lines.

Here is the test Markdown I have been using:

```html
<pre>let mut a = 5;
a += 5;
</pre>
```

I literally want to scream because of how much this issue has been bothering me.

I'll include the full code just incase it might be necessary.

```rust
use pulldown_cmark::{html, Parser};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use crate::colors::Paint;
use pad::PadStr;

pub fn parse_md(path: &str) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Read the markdown file
    let mut file = File::open(path)?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;

    // Split the contents by lines
    let lines = contents.lines();

    // Loop through the lines and find the shortest and longest line while in_pre is true
    let (mut shortest, mut longest) = (std::usize::MAX, 0);
    let mut in_pre = false;
    let mut formatted_lines = Vec::new();
    for line in lines {
        if line.starts_with("<pre>") {
            in_pre = true;
            continue;
        } else if line.starts_with("</pre>") {
            in_pre = false;
            continue;
        }

        if in_pre {
            let line_len = line.trim().len();
            if line_len < shortest {
                shortest = line_len;
            }
            if line_len > longest {
                longest = line_len;
            }
            formatted_lines.push(line);
        }
    }

    // Pad lines to the length of the longest line
    let formatted_lines: Vec<String> = formatted_lines
        .into_iter()
        .map(|line| {
            if line.trim().len() != longest {
                line.pad_to_width(longest)
            } else {
                line.to_string()
            }
        })
        .collect();

    // Convert the markdown to terminal text with ANSI escape codes
    let terminal_text = {
        // Parse the markdown to HTML
        let parser = Parser::new(&contents);
        let mut html_x = String::new();
        html::push_html(&mut html_x, parser);

        // Replace HTML tags with corresponding ANSI escape codes
        html_x.replace("<p>", "\n")
                            .replace("</p>", "\n")
            .replace("<strong>", "\x1b[1m")
            .replace("</strong>", "\x1b[22m")
            .replace("<em>", "\x1b[3m")
            .replace("</em>", "\x1b[23m")
            .replace("<code>", "\x1b[7m")
            .replace("</code>", "\x1b[27m")
            .replace("<blockquote>", "\x1b[38;5;242m")
            .replace("</blockquote>", "\x1b[39m")
            .replace("<h1>", "\x1b[38;5;33m\x1b[1m")
            .replace("</h1>", "\x1b[0m")
            .replace("<h2>", "\x1b[38;5;33m")
            .replace("</h2>", "\x1b[0m")
            .replace("<h3>", "\x1b[38;5;220m")
            .replace("</h3>", "\x1b[0m")
            .replace("<h4>", "\x1b[38;5;208m")
            .replace("</h4>", "\x1b[0m")
            .replace("<h5>", "\x1b[38;5;166m")
            .replace("</h5>", "\x1b[0m")
            .replace("<h6>", "\x1b[38;5;125m")
            .replace("</h6>", "\x1b[0m")
            .replace("<ul>", "")
            .replace("</ul>", "")
            .replace("<ol>", "")
            .replace("</ol>", "")
            .replace("<li>", " \x1b[33m• \x1b[0m")
            .replace("</li>", "")
            .replace("<a href=\"", "\x1b]8;;")
            .replace("\">", "\x1b\\")
            .replace("</a>", "\x1b]8;;\x1b\\")
    };

    // Display the formatted lines and terminal text
    for line in formatted_lines {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
    print!("{}", terminal_text);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't look at the line containing the `<pre>` so the longest line you consider is the only line *between* the lines containing `<pre>` and `</pre>`, `a += 5;` which leaves it the longest line, which doesn't need padding. Your current code assumes no code on the `<pre>` line, and [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce74002079eee025ad083125e9cd68a5) with input like this:

```html
<pre>
let mut a = 5;
a += 5;
</pre>
```

To also consider code that is on the same line as `<pre>` you can change your first if branch to the following:

```rust
        if let Some(line) = line.strip_prefix("<pre>") {
            let len = line.len();
            if len > 0 {
                formatted_lines.push(line);
                shortest = shortest.min(len);
                longest = longest.max(len);
            }
            in_pre = true;
            continue;
        }
```

[`strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.strip_prefix) does the `starts_with` check and removing the `<pre>` in one go and returns `Some` if it actually started with `<pre>` so the branch is entered in the same conditions, but now we also have access to the rest of it's contents.